# Cannot locate pygubu-designer.exe after instalation

Tags: python, tkinter, pygubu

I'm trying to install pygubu-designer, but the 'pygubu-designer.exe' never shows up in any of the folders after the installation process.
https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu
https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu-designer

I did:
pip install pygubu
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1ylH.png)

pip install pygubu-designer
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82vjE.png)

I have couple of folders with pygubu but pygubu-designer.exe is missing
[explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHFsu.png)

I have python 3.10.4 and pip 20.0.4 and python is added as system variable:
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sBvd.png)

I tried to upgrade pip version but it did not work

Comment: `pygubu-designer.exe` should be inside "c:\python310\Scripts\" directory.

Answer (score -1):

Could not locate pygubudesigner within my python310\Scripts folder and any other but the cmd command mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu/issues/222 worked for me

```
python -m pygubudesigner
```